# Can 32-bit Excel load add-in which is compiled by visual studio 64-bit compiler?

Tags: excel, visual-studio, add-in

I used my visual studio to compile my excel add-in(.xll) both under 32bit and 64bit platform. My computer installed excel which is 32-bit version and it can read 32-bit add-in properly but crashes when I drag 64-bit add-in in.

I google this problem and found many similar questions about if it's possible to loade 32bit add-in into 64 bit excel, but I am just wondering the other way around. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: As you found out, that is not possible.

Comment: No, you cannot load a 32-bit add-inn to a 64-bit version, or a 64-bit add-in to a 32-bit version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like ken White said, I found out both the version of excel and add-in should match each other, otherwise it wouldn't work.